# How can I stop asp.net encoding & in Get params?

Tags: asp.net, url, parameters, get

I am using the following code to add a series of calls to the body parameter of a page in asp.net:

```
uxBodyTag.Attributes["onbeforeunload"] += 
  "ajaxRequest('UnlockQuery.ashx?QueryID=" + queryId.ToString() + 
  "&UserID=" + Session["UserID"].ToString() + "');";
```

This is being rendered as:

```
<body id="uxBodyTag" onbeforeunload=
    "ajaxRequest('UnlockQuery.ashx?QueryID=176&amp;UserID=11648');">
```

The &amp; means my ashx page is not retrieving the correct variables - how can I stop asp.net from doing this?

EDIT:

Using 
    Server.UrlEncode 
gives me the following:

```
<body id="uxBodyTag" onbeforeunload=
 "ajaxRequest('UnlockQuery.ashx%3fQueryID%3d179%26UserID%3d11648')%3b">
```

Which is far worse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In HTML the ampersand needs to be encoded, always, everywhere, also in attribute values (the contents of the `<script>` tag is the notable exception, obviously). ASP.NET does the right thing.

Attribute values will be unencoded by the browser before it actually uses them. So your `onbeforeunload` attribute has a literal value of:

```
ajaxRequest('UnlockQuery.ashx?QueryID=176&UserID=11648');
```

while the HTML representation needs to have the `&amp;` in place of the `&`. The browser usually understands the ill-encoded version as well, but an SGML parser would complain about an unknown/invalid entity named `&UserID`.

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour you are seeing with & encoded as &amp; is the behaviour you want. By the time the text gets to your ajaxRequest function it will have been unencoded again and everything should be fine.

Comment: I'll check that - it seems I may have another issue at the moment, and this was the most obvious likely cause

Comment: A simple test is just to replace ajaxRequest with alert, you'll then see that your URL and query string is intact.