# Why is my onbeforeunload not running now when it was before? Or AJAX failing on second identical command?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, server-tags

This follows on from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564549/how-can-i-stop-asp-net-encoding-in-get-params) question

This **was** working:

```
<body onbeforeunload=
 "ajaxRequest('UnlockQuery.ashx?QueryID=266&UserID=11631');">
```

This was created using the following in the aspx page:

```
<body onbeforeunload=
 "ajaxRequest('UnlockQuery.ashx?QueryID=<%= Session["QueryId"] %>&
 UserID=<%= Session["UserID"] %>')">
```

This is **not** working:

```
<body id="uxBodyTag" onbeforeunload=
 "ajaxRequest('UnlockQuery.ashx?QueryID=266&amp;UserID=11631');">
```

This is created using:

```
uxBodyTag.Attributes["onbeforeunload"] += 
 "ajaxRequest('UnlockQuery.ashx?QueryID=" + 
 queryId.ToString() + "&UserID=" + Session["UserID"].ToString() + "');";
```

The code being called is this:

```
function ajaxRequest(url)
{
    xmlhttp=null;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {   // code for all new browsers
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject)
    {   // code for IE5 and IE6
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    if (xmlhttp!=null)
    {
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=null;
        xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
        xmlhttp.send(null);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

It appears to only fail when subsequent calls are made to the same unlock.  I think this may be an AJAX issue....

Comment: Just to make sure: can you place an "alert(url);" just before the "xmlhttp.open()" and tell what the output looks like?

Comment: Just tried:  UnlockQuery.ashx?QueryID=319&UserID=11648

Comment: Okay. What does "xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() { if (this.readyState == 4) alert(this.status + ": " + this.StatusText); };" say? I also suppose this is an issue in your app rather than in your client side code.

Comment: jquery ui 1.8.17 swallows my onbeforeunload event handler. After switching back to 1.8.16, my page is working again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding

```
&date=DateTime.now.Ticks.ToString()
```

seems to have fixed it.  I don't think IE7 likes it when the same AJAX call comes in and the previous hasn't been "resolved" (the page is disposed before the AJAX call returns).

Thanks to all that provided help.

Comment: I suppose the requests have been cached. You can try adding a Pragma: no-cache header to the response to prevent browser side caching entirely without having to change all your code.

Comment: In any case: Preventing browser-caching must be looked at from several angles. A single "Pragma: no-cache" is not sufficient for all situations, I suggest you look up some more info to make sure all browsers understand what you want.

Answer (score 1):

For the means of debugging, we tried:

```
alert(url);
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
```

which gave the expected result of:

```
UnlockQuery.ashx?QueryID=319&UserID=11648
```

Now we can check what the server has to say through:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
  if (this.readyState == 4) alert(this.status + ": " + this.StatusText); 
};
```

EDIT:

As it turns out, the browser cache was the reason for the unexpected results. I suggest to forbid caching the AJAX page through appropriate HTTP headers (`Pragma`, `Cache-Control`, `Expires`).